# How secure is sending an email using Python with SMTP Library?

Tags: python, smtplib, starttls

I've been experimenting with sending an email with Python. Before digging more into it, I wanted to check how secure is doing something like this. Using SMTP, Gmail won't let you do it unless you disable *2 Step Verification* and *Allow access to less secure apps in Gmail account settings*.

```
smtp.starttls(context=context)
```

Even tho that everything sent through the console is encrypted with TLS, what are the vulnerabilities of this technique?

Comment: Connecting over SMTP/TLS is no more or less secure than any other TLS connection.  However, in Google's case, your gmail password your Google account password, so leaking that password compromises the entire account (Calendar, Drive etc).  And people may hardcode their passwords into their email scripts.  So Google prefer to discourage programmatic SMTP access in favour of their client libraries, which use OAuth to limit access to specific scopes.